# Group by function with TOP 1 in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with columns `AppId`, `Comment`, `TimeStamp`. Table can have multiple entries for same `AppId`. Now what i am trying to do is to get `Top 1` `Comment` for each `AppId` Order by `TimeStamp` Desc.

I have tried something like

`SELECT TOP 1 Comment,
       AppId 
FROM comments
GROUP BY AppId`

but this doesnt seems to work as i get an error

`Column 'comments.Comment' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Can someone please point me in right direction on how to get this working

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your database engine, you may be able to use `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT Comment, AppId
FROM (
    SELECT Comment, AppId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AppId ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC) AS GroupRowNumber
    FROM comments
) AS sub
WHERE GroupRowNumber = 1
```

If you don't have that, you need something more hackish:

```
SELECT Comment, AppId
FROM comments
WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM comments AS comments_inner WHERE comments_inner.AppId = comments.AppId)
```